# Spring boot many to many relationship, query the join table

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, many-to-many

I have some specific questions regarding the many to many relationship in spring boot.

I have these two entities:

Book:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "books")
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Book {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "book_id")
private Long id;
private String name;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name="books_authors",joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="book_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="author_id"))
private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();
private String isbn;
private String genre;
private int pages;
}
```

Author:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "authors")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Author {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "author_id")
private Long id;
private String name;
private String age;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToMany(mappedBy="authors")
private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();

public Set<Book> getBooks() {
    return this.books;
}
}
```

Their DTOs are:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class BookDTO {
private Long id;
private Set<Author> authors = new HashSet<>();
private String name;
private String isbn;
private String genre;
private int pages;
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
public class AuthorDTO {
private Long id;
private String name;
private String age;
private Set<Book> books = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I have this service that assigns an author to a book:

```
public BookDTO assignExistingAuthorToBook(Long book_id, Long author_id) {
    Book book = bookRepository.findById(book_id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new BookNotFoundException(book_id));
    Author author = authorRepository.findById(author_id)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new AuthorNotFoundException(author_id));
    book.getAuthors().add(author);
    book.setAuthors(book.getAuthors());
    bookRepository.save(book);
    return modelMapper.map(book, BookDTO.class);
}
```

My questions are:

When I issue a GET request to postman to get a specific book that I have assigned an author to, the authors list is empty. But in the database I see that there is a row in the books_author relationship. Why is that? Is it wrong to have an author's list in BookDTO?

Also, if I want to query the join table, books_authors, how do I do it? Let's say I want to find all authors that dont have a book assigned to them. I would have to get all the id's from the authors, all the id's from the books_authors and then take their difference. But how do I query the books_authors? Is writting custom queries the only way to go about?

Thanks.